# Spark Connect usage

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying out Spark Connect for the first time and have a couple of questions about it

- Does Spark Connect support custom data connectors and session extensions in Scala? I have a regular Scala-based Spark application which connects to a data source via a custom data connector. I also use a custom SparkSessionExtension rule via injectResolutionRule() on the session. I currently use `spark-submit` to run my jobs. Is it possible to use Spark Connect to run the same functionality?
- Does `spark-shell` support the "remote" option for Spark Connect. I tried both the options suggested in the doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html). I.e. I set `export SPARK_REMOTE="sc://localhost"` and also ran `./bin/spark-shell --remote "sc://localhost"` but neither appears to work.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to get spark-connect working?

Answer (score 0):

I could not for sure answer the first part of your question.

However concerning the second part, you have missed a step with is starting the local Spark server, described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_connect.html#Launch-Spark-server-with-Spark-Connect).

Having done so, spark-shell will connect to the localhost via Spark Connect.